# How can I set an error margin on merging amount in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to dataframes which contains ID, Name, Amount and Stock details. 
Actual df details are as follows:

```
df1.shape - (1873, 3)
df2.shape - (1443, 4)

df1.columns - Index(['ID', 'Name', 'Amount'])
df2.columns - Index(['Name', 'gross total', 'Avail', 'date'])
```

In the first process the `merge(how=outer, left_on=['Name','Amount'], right_on=['Name', 'gross Value'], indicator=True]` I will get the exact matches. But as Name is not fully filled in Df2, I have to take the `left_only , right_only` again to two separate Dfs and merge them once again as `merge(how=outer, left_on='Amount', right_on='gross Value', indicator=True]`, ie just based on Value. This creates a less reliable df but I'm ok with it, at least I don't have to manually go through each line matching.

But the problem is the figures are rounded off, some up and some down. So On first and second time of merge, I want the Amount & gross value to be matched for a margin of +2 or -2. But as the rows and columns are all different I get a Value Error on `.between` as `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

How can I merge the values with a tolerance limit of $2.

**--------------------EDIT----------------**

Actual data extracts:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['100/2018-19', '67/2018-19', 'GAC/0054'], 'Name':['GUARD INDUSTRIES','GUARD INDUSTRIES','G-CHIEF APPLIANCES'],'Amount':[51428,1180400,24639]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['G-CHIEF APPLIANCES', 'ANIS INTERNATIONAL', 'GUARD INDUSTRIES', 'GUARD INDUSTRIES'], 'Avail':['S30','AK12', '46', '47'],'gross total':[24640,383675,51430,74360], 'Date':['22/02/2018', '22/02/2018', '22/02/2018', '23/02/2018'] })

Out:
            ID                Name   Amount
0  100/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES    51428
1   67/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES  1180400
2     GAC/0054  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES    24639

                 Name Avail  gross total        Date
0  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES   S30        24640  22/02/2018
1  ANIS INTERNATIONAL  AK12       383675  22/02/2018
2                 NaN    46        51430  22/02/2018
3    GUARD INDUSTRIES    47        74360  23/02/2018
```

As I do merge, I don't get any match:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True, left_on='Amount', right_on='gross total')

Out:
            ID                Name     Amount Avail  gross total        Date      _merge
0  100/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES    51428.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
1   67/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES  1180400.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
2     GAC/0054  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES    24639.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
3          NaN  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES        NaN   S30      24640.0  22/02/2018  right_only
4          NaN  ANIS INTERNATIONAL        NaN  AK12     383675.0  22/02/2018  right_only
5          NaN                 NaN        NaN    46      51430.0  22/02/2018  right_only
6          NaN    GUARD INDUSTRIES        NaN    47      74360.0  23/02/2018  right_only
```

*desired result* (As there are two rows with just $2 difference)

```
            ID                Name     Amount Avail  gross total        Date      _merge
0  100/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES    51428.0    46      51428.0  22/02/2018        both
1   67/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES  1180400.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
2     GAC/0054  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES    24639.0   S30      24639.0  22/02/2018        both
3          NaN  ANIS INTERNATIONAL        NaN  AK12     383675.0  22/02/2018  right_only
4          NaN    GUARD INDUSTRIES        NaN    47      74360.0  23/02/2018  right_only
```

In the desired result I gave gross total value as 24639 and 51428. I dont mind if it is 24640 and 51430 as in df2, I just want them to match.

when I try:

```
df1['in_margin'] = df1['Amount'].between(df2['gross total']-2, df2['gross total']+2)
df2['in_margin'] = df1['in_margin'].replace(False, -999)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Name','in_margin'], how='outer', indicator=True)
```

On that same line itself I get a value error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/../test margin.py", line 12, in <module>
    df1['in_margin'] = df1['Amount'].between(df2['gross total']-2, df2['gross total']+2)
  File "E:\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4364, in between
    lmask = self >= left
  File "E:\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "E:\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 521, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects```
````

Answer (score 0):

Create a True/False column in df1 called 'in_margin'.  Copy that to df2, replacing False with something else, such as a negative number then outer join and drop the in_margin column.

```
df1['in_margin'] = df1['Amount'].between(df2['Amount']-2, df2['Amount']+2)
df2['in_margin'] = df1['in_margin'].replace(False, -999)
df1.merge(df2, on=['item','in_margin'], how='outer', indicator=True).drop(columns='in_margin')
```

Output

```
item    Amount_x    Amount_y    _merge
0   A   100.0       98.0        both
1   B   100.0       102.0       both
2   A   40.0        NaN         left_only
3   A   NaN         35.0        right_only
```

Comment: Please check my edit part. I'm getting an error. I used a simple dataframe just to explain my desired output. @Chris

Comment: I think the error is because the data in both the df are not in line, like the first example. That is the matching entry for A may be in 400th row as compared to row 1 in df1.

Comment: try df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['ID','Name']).reset_index(drop=True) and do the same for df2.  After that they should be in the same order and have the same index.  After that proceed with the rest of the code

Comment: This works until I reach in a postion only merge on=Amount.... Is there a way to incorporate it in merge ?

Comment: can you perhaps update your question with a specific example

Comment: You need to show some actual data and indicate where the problem is.  From your current question I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Actual data extracts. With output what I get is added. Please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved my issue using `pd.merge_asof`. We can set a `tolerance` limit inside that with `direction=nearest`.